# How do I make a field "read only" in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

In my "User" template, I have a "userid" field, which is a "Single Line Text" control. I want to make this field "Read Only" for all user items being created using this template. How can I do this?

Comment: John West wrote a nice blog about this which you can read here:
https://www.sitecore.net/nederland/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/02/Render-Content-Editor-Fields-Read-Only-in-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx Generally when you want to create role based permission on Fields / Items you can use the Sitecore Documentation in the Sitecore Developer Network. The document you want to read is the Security Administrator's Cookbook.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the Security Editor, select the Role you want to give only read access.
Make sure you have the Field read en Field Write volumns visible in the Security Editor (open the Columns-option in the header menu).

[image: Display the Field Read and Field write columns]

Then disable the Field Write for the selected field. Repeat this for every other Role you want to give only read access.

[image]

The check the access for the specific user/role in the Access Viewer.

Comment: I want this field not being editable for Super admin users as well. Unfortunately Sitecore does not have a label control, if I have a label control kind of a thing this issue is solved. Can I get a Label control for Sitecore?

Comment: If you want it absolutely read-only for all users, you can use the the appropriate "Everyone" user for your field restriction instead of specific roles.

Comment: I take it you do this on the template not on the content item itself?