# Make a Field in Sitecore for a Content Editor Read only

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Is it possible to make a `Field` in a `Template` as Read only. So that the `Content Editor` is not able to edit this field in the `item`.

I have read [Sitecore make a field read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372969/sitecore-make-a-field-read-only) post but here the restrictions can be applied only to the users.

Comment: What do you mean the restriction can only be applied to the users? If you have roles set up (which you should) then it can be applied to multiple roles.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a field Read Only in the Content Editor via Security restrictions **for specific Role(s) not for specific User(s)**. Let me know if you need instructions.

Comment: So in the case where I want to restrict the Content Editor to edit a Field, which role should I select and then apply restrictions.